# how can delete a selected control in run time

Tags: c#

I have a form that in run time i make many picture box control and i located them on my form.
now my question is how can delete a picturebox(in run time) that it is been selected and keybord "delete" is entered.
thanks.

Comment: make use of PictureBox.KeyPress : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.keypress.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(pictureBox1);
        }
```

if delete on keyboard is selected the picture(has focus).

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Delete)
            {
                if(pictureBox1.Focus())
                {
                    this.Controls.Remove(pictureBox1);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

try below code in make use of PictureBox.KeyPress : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.keypress.aspx

```
 PictureBox picture = control as PictureBox;
    if (picture != null)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(picture);
        picture.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: how can understand "delet" key is entered??

Comment: @na.farzane = make use of PictureBox.KeyPress : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.keypress.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `PictureBox` from the controls and use the `ControlCollection.Remove` method.

Here is a sample code:

```
// Remove the PicturBox control if it exists.
private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if(panel1.Controls.Contains(pictureBox))
   {
      panel1.Controls.Remove(pictureBox);
   }
}
```

More documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove.aspx)

EDIT:

Refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) on how to monitor `KeyPress` events in C#

Comment: OP is asking for this being done in a Key event handler of the PictureBox. Is that possible?